# How to prevent horizontal scrollbar in latest release(s) of IntelliJ IDEA code windows from auto-hiding?

Tags: intellij-idea, horizontal-scrolling

**Is there a way to disable the "auto-hide" behaviour of the horizontal scrollbar?**

I often work with two side-by side code windows in IntelliJ IDEA, which makes horizontal scrolling necessary more often than not.

Recently I've noticed that in the code windows now (using `Build #IU-233.11799.241`, built on December 1, 2023 and the previous release), the IDE auto-hides the horizontal scrollbar in the coding panes. Other colleagues do not appear to have the `autohide` feature (presumably they have not updated the IDE recently). Anyway, it becomes increasingly annoying when the scrollbar disappears before you can reach it with your mouse pointer (when switching from keyboard to mouse navigation and having to waste extra movements to re-activate scrollbar visibility).

I see nothing in the Appearance Settings that helps...
[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ IDEA > Settings > Appearance configuration screen]

So, I repeat: **Is there a way to disable the "auto-hide" behaviour of the horizontal scrollbar** in the latest IntelliJ IDEA release's code panes?

TIA!

Comment: Can you share a screencast?